# Why are we not getting updated value of count, if both the threads are executing simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading

Two threads are executing in the given program simultaneously but this code is giving 0 output every time. why not updated values of count?

```
class ThreadA {        
    public static void main(String[] agrs) {
        ThreadB t = new ThreadB();
        t.start();  
        System.out.println(t.count);
    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread {
    int count = 0;
    public void run() { 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            count = count + i;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to insert a `Thread.sleep()` before printing?

Comment: if i am using Thread.sleep() then it is working fine. But, Why in the above code, count is not getting updated?

Answer (score 0):

*TLDR*:

```
t.join();
```

*Explanation*:

When you start ThreadB, the thread may be not immediately started. It is up to the scheduler to decide, which thread is executed at which time. Furthermore, ThreadA will not wait for ThreadB to finish its execution. So what happens (propably, as the scheduler can decide differently in every execution) is:

- ThreadA runs
- ThreadB is created
- ThreadA prints count
- (if the program would not terminate here: ThreadB is executed)

What you want is:

- ThreadA runs
- ThreadB is created
- ThreadA waits until ThreadB finished
- ThreadB does the calculations
- ThreadB finishes
- ThreadA prints count

You can achieve so by using the `join` method of the thread you want to wait for:

```
public static void main(String[] agrs) {
    ThreadB t = new ThreadB();
    t.start();
    t.join(); // Wait for ThreadB  
    System.out.println(t.count);
}
```

Comment: What if we don't use join()?

Comment: @DJoshi ThenThreadB will be terminated when ThreadA finishes. This might be before starting, while executing or after finishing (depending on what the scheduler does). And ThreadA can access the `count` variable of ThreadB at any time. So the result may vary from exection to execution.